# Search in the favourites

Tags: feature-request

I've few pages of favorite questions under my Favorites tab on Stack Overflow. If I want to refer something quickly, I've a hard time finding an old question. I've to go page by page and look for it. I know that I marked it some time before, but still having a hard time finding it again.

Is it possible to have a search functionality in the Favourites tag?

Comment: (Unrelated, but can you `not` 'tick' everything remotely related `to` code *as*  `code`? Some of your `posts` suffer from `this` as well. :P I detickified one `for` you.)

Comment: @Jongware `Unrelated` but, don't spent time in small things like `detickify`.  If you've nothing else to do go `beerify` yourself. `Detickify` will buy you 2 points. While `beerify` will buy you whole different level of happiness. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `infavorites:mine` when searching to search favorites, as it says right in the help text on the search page.